# UItableviewcell wonky display, they just can't get the screen width correctly with iphone6+. (objc)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I just made a login screen using uitableviewcell instead of uiscrollview for simplicity, but it turned out to be a disaster.

I color the cell green so you can see it clearly. Here's how it looks in iPhone6+:
[image]

And here's how it looked in iPhone 5:
[image]

So the problems here are the UILabel and UITextField doesn't get the ip6+ screensize. I use this code to set them up which should be getting the correct screen size

```
screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 44)];
UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.layer.bounds];
OR
UILabel *uiLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
```

**My main question would be, if UIScreen doesn't work, how do we get proper width for iphone 6+ ??**

Comment: You have a solution so I will just point out that Apple uses Autolayout / Constraints to deal with this situation. Rather than creating a fixed sized object you add constraints and the object will re-size to fit the screen size. As for your question, you have failed to log the output of the various frames or told us where your code runs so I cannot comment on if you have written your code correctly.

Comment: Hi @RoboticCat thanks for that. I am aware with AutoLayout but I'm just trying to experiment with code without AL. Regardless of AL or not, the code should still work, and indeed it did.

Answer (score 1):

The UITableViewCell will consider the width of the xib in the Interface Builder as its original width. If your xib is of iPhone 5 (i.e. 320 x 568), then the UITableViewCell's width will be set to 320px. If the xib in the IB is of iPhone 6+ (i.e. 414 x 736), the cell's width will be set as 414px.

To have a similar viewing experience in all devices, Apple recommends using Autolayout.

Just give the constraints to the tableview. Set the constraints of the tableview with respect to the superview and the UITableViewCell will automatically adjust with the screen size of the device. Also give the constraints to your UILabel.

Otherwise, you need to give screenWidth as width to the cell's content view and the UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after experimenting, this code solved the problem:

```
UILabel *uiLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 44)];
```

so lesson of the day:

contentView.frame and contentView.layer.bounds **DOESN'T** get the correct cell size from UITableViewCell. Not sure why.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks!